# Url parameter and specific conditions

Tags: javascript

I have this url

```
http://www.example.com/ln-en/Category/Product/Product-A/Details
```

if I use this if condition

```
(window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-A" || window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-B" || window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-C" || window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Intro" || window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "vol-A-Free" || window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "vol-B")
```

and I take the result `true`

However if I use only this

```
window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-A"
```

I take back `false` with is what I was expecting to give also the first condition. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href.split("/")[6]` is `"Product-A"`.

Therefore:

`window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-A"` is `false`

and

`window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-B"` is `true`

and

```
window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-"A" || window.location.href.split("/")[6] !== "Product-B"
```

is the same as

```
false || true
```

which is `true`.

You probably want to use `&&` conditions in your test.

Comment: What I want to make with the big condition is if the window.location.href.split("/")[6] if not equal with all the values I have go to the if statement

Comment: @therin — Yes, see the last sentence in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The expression will always return `true` because there is always one of the `|` (or) criterias that is true. You could use an array `indexOf` instead :

```
var products =["Product-A", "Product-B", "Product-C", "Intro", "vol-A-Free", "Vol-B"];

console.log(products.indexOf(window.location.href.split("/")[6]));
```

or

```
console.log(products.indexOf(window.location.href.split("/")[6])>-1);
```